# File manager stopped working on Linux system

Tags: linux, filesystems, fedora, php, btrfs

Somehow Nautilus stopped working on Linux fedora and now I am unable to use any file manager.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Nautilus and even installed other file manager but nothing works.

Instead I am getting this error every time I try to start it:

Bus error (core dumped)

And in logs I am getting:

`csum failed root 256 ino 27xxxx off 0 csum 0x6xxxxxxx expected csum 0x5xxxxxxx mirror 1`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Filesystem of /

Comment: It's warning in the log in /

Comment: what is the filesystem of root partition

Comment: Filesystem is btrfs

Comment: Try : btrfs scrub status / ; check if it fixes the issue

Comment: Giving me unrecoverable 52 errors.

Comment: Did check repair but didn't worked

Comment: edit the question and add the result/output

Comment: Error summary:  csum=106  Corrected: 0 Uncorrectable: 106   Unverified: 0